# upgrade percona-server package fails

Tags: 12.04, upgrade, mysql

This has been happening for a few weeks.  Every other package upgrades without issue except this one, but I'm not sure what's causing this or how to debug it.

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be upgraded:
  percona-server-server-5.5
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/22.1 MB of archives.
After this operation, 845 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? 

Preconfiguring packages ...


(Reading database ... 684209 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace percona-server-server-5.5 5.5.30-rel30.1-465.precise (using .../percona-server-server-5.5_1%3a5.5.30-rel30.2-503.precise_amd64.deb) ...
 * Stopping MySQL (Percona Server) mysqld                                                                                                                                                                [fail] 
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "stop" failed.
dpkg: warning: subprocess old pre-removal script returned error exit status 1
dpkg - trying script from the new package instead ...
 * Stopping MySQL (Percona Server) mysqld                                                                                                                                                                [fail] 
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "stop" failed.
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/percona-server-server-5.5_1%3a5.5.30-rel30.2-503.precise_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess new pre-removal script returned error exit status 1
 * Stopping MySQL (Percona Server) mysqld                                                                                                                                                                [fail] 
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "stop" failed.
 * Starting MySQL (Percona Server) database server mysqld                                                                                                                                                [ OK ] 
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/percona-server-server-5.5_1%3a5.5.30-rel30.2-503.precise_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: What happens if you shut down the Percona Server yourself? `stop mysql-server` Also inspect the log files (syslog or other log you enabled for Percona).

Comment: gertvdijk's tip works for me: service mysql stop && aptitude safe-upgrade

Answer (score 2):

Stop mysql first. Then run the update. It should then work.

Edit.
Before you run the update try

```
sudo service mysql stop
```

then

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Then you can do

```
service mysql start
```

If you still have trouble then you might want to check that the "sudo service mysql stop" command leaves no MySQL processes behind.  You can check for processes with the following command. Interpreting the output of ps is beyond the scope of this answer
    ps -ef |grep mysql

However for completeness here is what I get when MySQL is running

```
root@control:~# ps -ef |grep mysql
root      1304     1  0 Oct24 ?        00:00:00 /bin/sh /usr/bin/mysqld_safe
mysql     2568  1304  6 Oct24 ?        10:55:04 /usr/sbin/mysqld --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql/ --plugin-dir=/usr/lib/mysql/plugin --user=mysql --log-error=/var/lib/mysql/mysql-error.log --open-files-limit=65535 --pid-file=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.pid --socket=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
root      4492 23102  0 11:32 pts/3    00:00:00 grep --color=auto mysql
```

... and when MySQL is stopped ...

```
root@control:~# ps -ef |grep mysql
root      4492 23102  0 11:32 pts/3    00:00:00 grep --color=auto mysql
```

Comment: Welcome to AU! We value and encourage [high-quality answers](/help/how-to-answer). While your answer sounds generally helpful, it gives readers only a rough idea what to do. Can you describe in detail the steps necessary to enact your solution?

Comment: Hey Dave. I've updated my answer! Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem, the only way I was able to solve it was killing mysql:

```
ps aux | grep mysql 
mysql     1325 10.3  3.3 2216444 309324 ?      Sl   Sep24  22:38 /usr/sbin/mysqld --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --plugin-dir=/usr/lib/mysql/plugin --user=mysql --log-error=/var/
lib/mysql/ecom-mysql.err --pid-file=/var/lib/mysql/ecom-mysql.pid --socket=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock --port=3306

sudo kill  -9 1325    
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Answer (score 0):

I too had this problem on Debian Wheezy. All I could do was to kill the mysql process manually, run my apt-get update, and that worked fine.

Comment: Welcome to AU! We value and encourage [high-quality answers](/help/how-to-answer). While your answer sounds generally helpful, it gives readers only a rough idea what to do. Can you describe in detail the steps necessary to enact your solution? I suspect that it's going to be the same as the other two answers though.